# Resubscribe to an observable from a header component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Observable that basically displays a countdown timer for a user ecomm order when they hit a certain route after adding to cart. This lives in an Angular service. This code works great the first time I enter an ecomm order but if I complete the order or navigate away and then re-enter the order flow the countdown timer does not work. I believe its because the timer$ observable has completed.

```
export class TimerService {
public timer$: Observable<string> = timer(0, 200).pipe(
 takeWhile(() => Boolean(this.lockExpiration)),
 map(() => this.calculateSecondsLeft(this.lockExpiration)),
 takeWhile((timeLeft) => this.lockExpiration >= new Date(this.lockExpiration.getTime() - timeLeft), true),
 map(this.createCountdownString),
 shareReplay()
) as ReplaySubject<string>;

constructor() { }
....
```

the code that subscribed to timer$ is in a header angular component
so example:

```
<header></header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

the header component subscribes in ngOnit:

```
 this.timer = this.seatLockTimer.timer$.subscribe({
              next: timeLeft => {
                console.log('next');
                this.timeLeft = timeLeft;
              }, complete: () => {
                console.log('complete');
                this.timeLeft = null;
              }
            });
```

and the template:

```
<div id="countdownTimer" *ngIf="timeLeft">{{timeLeft}}</div>
```

so again the issue is when I navigate away and then try to purchase something else `console.log('complete');` was called because of this line `takeWhile(() => Boolean(this.lockExpiration)),` because on navigate away we want and need to clear the lockExpiration (which acts as the countdown timer minutes left) and thus the header component will not re-subscribe.

is there a way to accomplish this? I have tried trying to re-call ngOnit for the header component but not having much luck

I am thinking of 2 options:
having to move the timer subscription out of the header component or have another process beside ngOnit decide when to subscribe

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `ActivatedRoute` for this, although since you're in the header context that may not work. i.e.,

```
this.route.url
  .pipe(
    switchMapTo(timer(0, 200)),
    //etc.
  )
```